# ZFS NAS: PCI-e x1 SATA or built-in ICH10R?

Tags: solaris, pci, nas, zfs, sata

I am planning to install Nexenta (or NexentaStor, I've not decided yet) to build a ZFS NAS out from the following machine:

- MB: Intel DG45FC
- Disks: 4x 2TB WD caviar green
- RAM: 2x 2GB of non-ECC Kingston (I can't afford ECC)
- System disk: 2x 500GB 2.5'' WD to host a mirrored pool for the system and maybe another mirrored pool for high-priority data

**Problem:** The MB has only 5 SATA (4 internals + 1 eSATA) ports, whereas I need 4 + 2 SATA ports. I foresee two options:

1) **Attach the system disks on the MB controller** and buy a 2-port PCI-e x1 SATA card. Issue: Does anyone know the throughput of the ICH10R with Solaris ZFS in RAID5 mode?

2) **Buy a 4-ports PCI-e x1 SATA card.** Because I am not sure the ICH10R in AHCI mode is very fast, I am also thinking of buying a supported card with decent speed. Issue: I can't find a PCI-e x1 card that is supported and has 4 ports. This comprehensive list http://blog.zorinaq.com/?e=10 doesn't seem to have any that are compatible with my settings.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICH10R should be fast enough for 4x2 TB WD green and I would recommend to connect the 4x2TB disks to the motherboard and the system disks to an add-on SATA controller.

Another issue to consider is to use data disks optimized for RAID operation instead of WD green (such as WD RAID edition).

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to get an add-in PCIe x1 controller as your ICH10R supports port multipliers and thus isn't limited to just 1 device per sata channel. Buy something like an [Addonics AD5SAPM 5x1 Port Multiplier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031X58H8) which sits in a empty PCI bay and will let up to five devices share a single SATA channel.  Performance of these devices will be capped at single channel SATA2 max speed (300MB/sec) but that's still better than what you'd get in aggregate with any PCIe x1 device (250MB/sec).

Be aware that the Caviar 2TB Caviar Green disks have 4K sectors, but lie and report 512byte sectors to the OS.  At pool creation time make sure to specify `ashift=12` so that ZFS can align everything to 4K boundaries otherwise your performance will be terrible.

Comment: Thats great !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! +1  For large data storage with out the need for maximum performance like my home NAS server.. MINT! bloody amazing bro! Thanks